# color calibration and 3d acceleration

Tags: drivers, nvidia, color-management

I am a photographer and I am looking at moving to Ubuntu in the near future. I also enjoy playing games. I am planning on building a new computer specifically for Ubuntu.

I've been doing some testing with a laptop that has an nvidia graphics chip in it and I've discovered that I can use the gnome color calibration tool to calibrate my display using my ColorMunki. However, if I install the nvidia driver so I can play a video game, I am unable to calibrate my display.

My question is, does either the AMD driver or Intel driver have this same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of nvidia drivers affecting the color managment portion of the OS. All i can say is, make sure to have a .icm prepared already for the linux system, rather than try and make one after you install.

What your problem might be also, stems from OpenGL. In many cases, games with OpenGL will cause the color profile to be disabled, meaning you have to re-load the color profiles.

That's all I got, good luck.